# Pydeequ - Datatype check for datetime column

Tags: pyspark, amazon-deequ

We are implementing Pydeequ process for doing certain validations including data type check (using verification suite).

However based on the understanding, the hasDataType fucntion can be used only for validating against the following - any thoughts on how a field can be checked for date / datetime data type check.

[image]

Comment: Did you get anything!